# How to open android original system keyBoard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an application that works fine with android "original" default keyboard but has issues with some custom keyboards.
Is it possible to always pop-up the android "original" keyboard regardless the has user installed a custom keyboard?

I know the best way is to write my own keyboard class but currently I don't have the time and I need a quick fix.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what is you exact problem with the keyboards? I don't think it makes sense to write your own keyboard. Is you problem that some of the keyboards does not popup on the screen when you focus in the edit field?

Comment: some of the custom keyboards popup but aren't responsive. The user can't type anything.

Comment: this custom keyboard have you installed it in your phone if so that's the culprit. As android always opens the stock(default) keyboard

Comment: It is better to fix the problem with your app rather fixing the problem on the keyboards, I mean think of it no body will want to use the old android keyboard after some time and there is a reason why google is updating the soft keyboards or why there are many soft keyboards out there. It is for better usability.

Comment: Shay, are you sure that when the keyboard is popuped the edit text is focused?

Comment: There are many users using my app and some of them have installed different kinds of custom keyboard.
I need a quick fix for those users who can't type in my app.
The problem is the keyboard pops up but it's not responding.
I am planning to write my own custom keyboard for the next app version, but it will take some time because it needs to support several languages.

Comment: Yanislav Mihaylov - yes i'm sure the edit text is focused.